# On invariant cones of the Katok map

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-dynamics, discrete-dynamical-systems

I am studying the Katok map and similarly constructed examples of nonuniformly hyperbolic surface diffeomorphisms. An important part of the analysis of these diffeomorphisms is the invariance of a continuous family of stable and unstable cones, but I'm having trouble understanding part of the argument. (I apologize if this question is inappropriately specific for a certain paper, but I've seen this argument frequently enough that I think there's something fundamental I'm missing. The core of the relevant construction is summarized below.)

The Katok map is derived from the hyperbolic automorphism $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)$ of the torus $\mathbb T^2$, which in a neighborhood of the origin has a coordinate neighborhood $(s_1, s_2)$ where the automorphism is the time-1 map of the flow generated by the following vector field:
$$
\dot s_1 = s_1\log\lambda, \quad \dot s_2 = -s_2 \log\lambda
$$
where $\lambda > 1$ is an eigenvalue of the above matrix. To construct the Katok map, we slow down the map in this neighborhood with a function $\psi : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ which satisfies $\psi(0) = 0$, $\psi'(u) > 0\, \forall u \in (0,1]$, $\psi(u) = 1 \, \forall u \geq r_0$ (for some $r_0 > 0$), and $\int_0^1 \psi(u)^{-1}\,du < \infty$. We define the map $G$ to be the above automorphism outside of $D_{r_0} \subset \mathbb T^2$, and inside this disc the time-1 map of the flow generated by the vector field $V_\psi$, defined by:
$$
\dot s_1 = s_1 \psi(s_1^2 + s_2^2) \log\lambda, \quad \dot s_2 = -s_2 \psi(s_1^2 + s_2^2)\log\lambda.
$$
(Strictly speaking we then conjugate by a homeomorphism to make this map Lebesgue-area preserving, but it suffices to consider the map we have just constructed.)

We let $(\xi_1, \xi_2)$ be the standard coordinates of $T_x\mathbb T^2$ for $x \in \mathbb T^2$, and define the *unstable* and *stable* cones respectively as
\begin{align}
K^+_x &:= \left\{(\xi_1, \xi_2) \in T_x\mathbb T^2 : |\xi_1| \geq |\xi_2| \right\} ,\\
K^-_x &:= \left\{(\xi_1, \xi_2) \in T_x \mathbb T^2 : |\xi_1| \leq |\xi_2|\right\}
\end{align}
The goal is to prove $dG_x(K^+_x) \subset K^+_{G(x)}$ and $dG_x^{-1}(K^-_x) \subset K^-_{G^{-1}(x)}$. The argument for $K^+_x$ runs as follows (paraphrased from a few sources), and the argument for $K^-_x$ is similar:

> The linear part of the vector field $V_\psi$ is
>   \begin{align}
> \frac{d\xi_1}{dt} &= (\log\lambda)\left(\xi_1\left(\psi+2s_1^2\psi'\right)+2s_1s_2\xi_2\psi'\right), \\
> \frac{d\xi_2}{dt} &= -(\log\lambda)\left(2s_1s_2\xi_1\psi'+\xi_2\left(\psi+2s_2^2\psi'\right)\right)
> \end{align}
>   The equation for the tangent $\alpha = \xi_2/\xi_1$ is
>   $$
> \frac{d\alpha}{dt} = -2(\log\lambda)\left(\alpha\left(\psi+\left(s_1^2+s_2^2\right)\psi'\right)+s_1s_2\left(\alpha^2+1\right)\psi'\right)
> $$
>   Substituting $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=-1$ into this equation gives us
>   \begin{align}
> \frac{d\alpha}{dt} &= -2(\log\lambda)\left(\psi + \left(s_1+s_2\right)^2\psi'\right)\leq 0, \\
> \frac{d\alpha}{dt} &= 2(\log\lambda)\left(\psi+\left(s_1-s_2\right)^2\psi'\right)\geq 0.
> \end{align}
>   These inequalities are strict everywhere except the origin. This proves cone invariance.

This argument confuses me. In the equations for $d\xi_i/dt$, is $(\xi_1(t), \xi_2(t))$ supposed to be the vector field $V_\psi$ at a point along a certain trajectory? If so, then $\xi_i = \dot s_i$, and $\alpha$ would be the slope of the tangent vector at that point. The calculations work out in that case, but that seems too restrictive to be useful. Is this what they mean by "tangent"? How does this prove invariance of $K^+_x$ under $dG$?